# OpenERP name generator

Tags: odoo, erp

I'm exploring ERP options for my businnes with tyres. I've found OpenERP, which is compatible with my Synology NAS and I'm trying to generate product list. I've instaled product_variant_multi with dimension types "Width", "Profile", "Diameter", "Speed rating". I want the name generator to generate it like **Width/Profile Diameter Speed rating**. The default name generating code is:

```
[_o.dimension_id.name_] - [_o.option_id.name_]
```

This code generates names by separating dimension types with dash, which is not usable for me. I do not understand the syntax so I'd like to ask you for help with this, how can I write a code which will generate the names the way I want it to? Something like:

```
[_Width_]/[_Profile_] [_Diameter_] [_Speed rating_]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some explanation about the default name generating code:

o = the table product_variant_dimension_value

From there you can access all columns of the table

o.price_extra to show the price_extra

o.dimension_id.name = you get the name of the product_variant_dimension_type linked to your product_variant_dimension_value record

If you tell me where you Width, Profile... are stored I can give you the syntax

Comment: Hello Yannick, thanks for the reply. "Width" is a dimension type and it has options like "200","190" and so on. So I would like to generate `o.dimension_id(1).name` where the 1 is the id of "Width" dimension type. How can I do this?